# C# Json response to model

Tags: c#, json

I have an HTTP call that returns the below, and I am trying to convert the coversio_rates into a returnable model, some of the values get populated, but converio_rates are always null.

```
string response = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;   
var typetoReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info>(response);
```

but the values never the set.

API response model example

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "documetatio": "https: //www.exchagerate-api.com/docs",
    "terms_of_use": "https://www.exchagerate-api.com/terms",
    "time_last_update_uix": 1631266201,
    "time_last_update_utc": "Fri, 10 Sep 2021 09:30:01 +0000",
    "time_ext_update_uix": 1631352601,
    "time_ext_update_utc": "Sat, 11 Sep 2021 09:30:01 +0000",
    "base_code": "USD",
    "coversio_rates": {
        "USD": 1,
        "AED": 3.6725,
        "AF": 81.8475,
        "ALL": 102.7736,
        "AMD": 492.9916,
    }
}
```

Model Coversio_Rates

```
public class Coversio_Rates 
{
  
    public float USD { get; set; }
    public float AED { get; set; }
    public float AF { get; set; }
    public float ALL { get; set; }
    public float AMD { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string result { get; set; }
    public string documetatio { get; set; }
    public string base_code { get; set; }
    public Coversio_Rates Coversio_Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to deserialize the whole response, not just part of it.  Also, if you are dealing with currencies then you should use Decimal, not float (or string!).

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` for `Coversio_Rates`, this will automatically use `USD` etc as the keys

Answer (score 1):

You need a wrapper class since those properties are child values. For example:

```
public class Root
{
    public Coversio_Rates Coversio_Rates { get; set; }
    // Add in the other properties if you want them too
}
```

Now do:

```
var typetoReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
```

Some other points:

1. Use decimal instead of string for the currency values
2. NEVER use `.Result`, instead you should `await` the task.
3. Consider naming your class `CoversioRates` as that is a more common best practice in C# code. Same goes for the property name, but you will need to add a `[JsonProperty("Coversio_Rates")]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, found the issue, i spelling :(